# What is the Zen kernel?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel

I recently stumbled upon the zen kernel on the Arch wiki, but neither the wiki nor the Github page says anything more. What is it? Is its performance really better?

Comment: Why a downvote? It's a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 11):

The best summary I know of currently is [Liquorix’s](https://liquorix.net/) (Liquorix packages the [Zen kernel](https://github.com/zen-kernel/zen-kernel/) for Debian and other distributions):

- the kernel is tuned to increase the preemption frequency
- the default I/O scheduler is changed to BFQ (high throughput, low latency)
- the default process scheduler is changed to MuQSS, with high-frequency scheduling
- real-time preemption is enabled
- TCP congestion control is changed to BBR

Whether that increases performance for you will depend on your workloads.